# Why does the output of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and file_get_contents("php://input") differ?

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.4

I'm fairly new to PHP and in the process of updating a system from PHP5 to PHP7.

`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is deprecated in PHP7 and I had read that `file_get_contents("php://input")` was it's equivocal replacement.

I have tested them against each other using PHP5 and found that they produce different data as follows:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $data;
$data = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
echo $data;
```

with output:

```
pid=395,
,
```

In the first case the data contains the form content, in the second it doesn't. This variable being identified as empty was how the query was parsed for different purposes.

Have I missed something?

Comment: I know for a fact that file_get_contents("php://input") returns all data that was passed to php's runtime STDIN. It works from the command line if you pipe data into PHP.exe or the linux executable. 

HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA describes itself as pertaining to the *data* passed on via *HTTP POST* requests. It seems to me that that is not exactly the same thing.

Comment: For my uses, I'm going to use `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` to filter the requests, but everything I've read suggests that these two methods are equivocal and as you say, it seems they're not.

Comment: maybe http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

Comment: and try print in other order

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko Why did you remove your answer? It seems to be the reight answer.

Comment: @RandomSeed but that didn't answer the question

Comment: Are you referring to Lathrisk's comment " I assume it would have produced a deprecation error". This is normal, the variable was removed, accessing a non-existent variable only produces a notice.